# Windows 8 GridView - Parallax Background Image

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

any idea on how to implement a parallax effect on gridview when scrolling it?
I'm looking for an effect similar to the windows home screen, that moves background image when scrolling.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to handle the [ScrollViewer.ViewChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.viewchanged.aspx) on the ScrollViewer used to scroll your GridView and update positioning of an image in the background. You can get the ScrollViewer using the [WinRT XAML Toolkit](http://bit.ly/WinRTXamlToolkit)'s [VisualTreeHelperExtensions](http://bit.ly/VisualTreeHelperExtensions) extension method - essentially

```
ScrollViewer myScrollViewer = myScrollViewermyGridView.GetFirstDescendantOfType<ScrollViewer>();
myScrollViewer.ViewChanged += UpdateBackgroundImagePosition;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I'm able to move the image control using TranslateTransform based on Scrollviewer's HorizontalOffset, but the image is cutted (of course) when scrolling completely to the right. I would like to repeat the image

Comment: Yes, TranslateTransform only transforms what is otherwise rendered on screen. You can host the image in something like a Grid and manipulate the Margins of your image to move it or use a Canvas and manipulate Canvas.Left property.

Answer (score 0):

1) Name your ScrollViewer something like MyScrollviewer

2) Add a RenderTransform to your background user interface element like this:

```
  <your background.RenderTransform>
    <CompositeTransform TranslateX="{Binding ElementName=MyScrollViewer, Path=HorizontalOffset, Converter={StaticResource ParallaxConverter}}" />
  </your background.RenderTransform>
```

3) Implement a ParallaxConveter (multiplies by -.1)

See http://w8isms.blogspot.com/2012/06/metro-parallax-background-in-xaml.html for exquisite details.

Comment: "1) Name your ScrollViewer something like MyScrollviewer" There is only a GridView